# Using Excel to Find Optimal Meeting Times

Tags: performance, scheduling

Given a set of people's availabilities across multiple days (e.g. Monday, 9-10 AM ET, 2-3 PM ET, etc), how can one use Excel (solver?) to find the optimal meeting times (i.e. overlaps in schedule availabilities), or at least find the best solution?

Thinking of this as an optimization problem.

Comment: this can be solved with graph paper and crayons

Comment: Sure, but as schedules shift or for new meetings, it would be nice to have an Excel file to recycle.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? You're asking for a complex solution without demonstrating any effort you've put in on your own. This site works best answering narrow and specific questions rather than providing involved solutions. I recommend you begin solving this yourself, breaking the problem down to component parts and as you come upon specific parts you are unable to solve, share those here for us to assist with.